# Convergence with probability one - example discrete problem with two-series theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be independent sequence of r.v.s with distribution $\mathbb{P}(X_n = n)=\mathbb{P}(X_n = -n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) = 1 - \frac{2}{n^2}$. Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ converge with probability 1? What is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}VarX_n$?

I thought about using Kolmogorov's two-series theorem to do so.

Now, I have calculated $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}X_n = 0 < \infty$ because:

$$
\mathbb{E}X_n = n \frac{1}{n^2} - n\frac{1}{n^2} + 0 \cdot(1 -\frac{2}{n^2}) = 0
$$

$VarX_n = \mathbb{E}X_n^2 - (\mathbb{E}X_n)^2 = \mathbb{E}X_n^2 - 0 = \mathbb{E}X_n^2$ so:

$$
\mathbb{E}X_n^2 = n^2\frac{1}{n^2} +(-n)^2\frac{1}{n^2} + 0^2 \cdot(1 -\frac{2}{n^2}) = 2
$$

Thus $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}VarX_n = \infty$.

Unfortunately, that means I can't use the theorem because it does not say anything about the convergence if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}VarX_n = \infty$. What else could be done here? Maybe there's an error in my calculation? Should I use three series theorem?

Comment: Hint: Use Borel-Cantelli and the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(| X_k - 0| > \epsilon) < \infty$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_k| > c)$ is convergent for arbitrary $c > 0$ because $\mathbb{P}(|X_k| > c)$ is at most $\frac{1}{k^2}$ which give us converging series. Did I get it right? I'd still need a converging variance series to use Three Series Theorem. Where do I need Borel-Cantelli?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев Do not use three series theorem. Just use Borel Cantelli Lemma as I have done in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum P(X_n \neq 0)=P(X_n=n)+P(X_n=-n)=\sum (\frac 1 {n^{2}}+\frac 1 {n^{2}}) <\infty$. By Borel Cantelli Lemma it follows that $X_n=0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, with probability $1$. So the series converges with probability $1$.